# How to show a custom range within a default range

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing, ux-designer

I currently have a range of values where the center of the graph represents the ideal value, and the further you get away from the center the worse your value is. In this current wireframe, you can see that the green is good, orange is ok, red is bad. [image]

When the graph crosses over from one color to another, the user will get a notification letting them know about the value change. If the user creates a custom range to get a notification (i.e. they select a range of 75-90), how can I visualize the custom value on the graph? I tried to "highlight" the custom range, but I feel that it would be difficult to see on a small screen (the graph takes up the horizontal space of a screen and is not very tell vertically)
[image]

Is there a clearer way to visualize the custom range on the default range values?

Comment: Would the notification be sent when the value falls outside the range, or when it enters the range? For example, if it goes below 75 or above 90, is that when it's sent?

Comment: Giving feedback using colour-only isn't a very accessible practice. What about people who are colourblind?

Comment: @MikeM The notification would be sent when it falls outside the custom range (below 75 or above 90) and also when it falls outside the default range (i.e. when it goes from green to orange, or orange to red)

Comment: @JonW There are icons within each color of the graph to account for colorblindess, but maybe they are too small for the user to notice

Comment: @GeneLee so there's basically 2 notifications. One mandatory (the default), the other custom?

Comment: @MikeM Yeah that would be correct, two different notifications with the custom being, well, customizable as well as optional. The default is mandatory and noncustomizable

Answer (score 1):

##### Try to separate out a notification range text, with an explicit label.

This way the user can just read the values pertaining to the notification. If you defined a really small range, it would clutter the visualization.

This way you have two chunks:

1. The actual range
2. The rules on notifications (the threshold a user feels they should be interrupted about)

[image]

Another possibility is to enable / disable this as a small widget. The writing is kind of stilted, but here's the general idea.

[image]